# Azure webapps having same ip

Tags: azure

i created a resource group and multiple web apps under it. now trying to map custom domains to those apps but the ip address is the same for both the apps. i referred to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/05/05/how-to-get-a-static-ip-address-for-your-microsoft-azure-web-site/) but to setup A record I need a static ip before mapping the domains.

Answer (score 1):

To run 2 websites as described by the OP

1. a.azurewebsites.net and
2. b.azurewebsites.net,

Both have the same IP address X.X.X.X (reason yet to be explained adequately).
I have a wild card domain *.domain.com and want the

1. *.domain.com traffic to go to a.azurewebsites.net
2. api.domain.com to go to my b.azurewebsites.net

Traffic is working with the following configurations:

DNS HOST:

1. A, domain.com -> X.X.X.X
2. CNAME *.domain.com -> a.azurewebsites.net
3. CNAME api.domain.com -> b.azurewebsites.net

AZURE PORTAL 
Open webapp a.azurewebsites, Custom Domains, Hostnames assigned ot site:

1. domain.com
2. *.domain.com
3. a.azurewebsites.net

Open webapp b.azurewebsites, Custom Domains, Hostnames assigned ot site:

1. api.domain.com
2. a.azurewebsites.net

Answer (score 0):

Web Apps on Azure often share IP addresses. This doesn't matter. You can map the custom domain as you would normally. The server will know which app you are accessing based on the `Host` header sent by browsers.

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses may be same for all apps when all apps are hosted in same server.You have to create an A record pointing to the apps IP address and also a TXT record that points to the azure app domain name (yourapp.azurewebsites.net).This TXT record is different from one app to another.

Azure document says...

> To use an A record to map to your Azure app's IP address, you actually
>   need to create both an A record and a TXT record. The A record is for
>   the DNS resolution itself, and the TXT record is for Azure to verify
>   that you own the custom domain name.

You can find more details here. [Map a custom domain name to an Azure app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name#a)